# Clarification re the term "Application Infrustructure"

Tags: oop, architecture

Apologies if what I am going to ask is too generic and please feel free to mark it as community wiki or even close it but after getting a good answer please.. Here goes nothing.

I had a heated debate over the term application infrastructure with a consultant from a BIG company and hence I am here to see what the experts think as I myself need a good understanding as well. I am a puny software developer and was trying to have a chat about software architecture and stuff and then we kinda got stuck up at the term application infrastructure.

As per my rival's understanding, this is solely used re the back-end hardware components and whereas I thought he is mixing the contexts and from the context of software eng it should refer to stuff that supports the application such as logging, ORM, or even framework (.net) etc.

To what extent am I wrong and if I am please shed some light on the definition...it's really gonna help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: I agree with you. App IF is not only HW, but includes SW entities too. I cant think of any references, etc I'll let others do that :)

Comment: Please do! I found it to be a really interesting topic myself considering the fact that I dunno much about so many things!

Comment: Let me guess, he's a HW guy, right? Its all a matter of context and comfort zones. His "understanding" seem rather narrow-minded, whereas yours seems to be thinking about the big picture. If what you mention as App IF isnt actually App IF, then ask him what its called then.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is really simple: the term "Application infrastructure" is ambiguous.

Comment: few more answers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few links with a little description about the term `Application Infrastructure` extracted from them:

- [Application Infrastructure -- f5.com](http://www.f5.com/pdf/application-briefs/application-infrastructure-ab.pdf)

  Application infrastructure, comprised of application servers, web servers, and often database servers, is a core component in most network architectures. This part of the network infrastructure delivers high performance application services to the LAN as well as to employees, partners and customers on the WAN.

  Some of the key functionality of application infrastructure includes transaction management, clustering, reliable application-to-application messaging, system management, advanced application development tools, proprietary access, and interoperability with legacy technologies.
- [Application Infrastructure -- networkmagazineindia.com](http://www.networkmagazineindia.com/200212/inperson1.shtml)

  A (common/standard) platform is required to make different applications in an enterprise work across geographies or multiple locations, and to manage a large number of users and transactions taking place within an enterprise. This platform which ensures that different applications work with each other, is known as an application infrastructure.
- [Application Infrastructure -- bitpipe.com](http://www.bitpipe.com/tlist/Application-Infrastructure.html)

  A high performance, reliable, and secure integrated technology infrastructure for managing multiple hosted applications by Application Service Providers.

Answer (score 0):

What he seem to be describing is the *platform for software* (I'll leave it open if that is the same thing as the *software platform*.  I do include software service in the Application Infrastructure definition and also include connectivity/networking along with hardware and software as the three foundation corner stones of Infrastructure.  Infrastructure is the general purpose commodity components as opposed to the domain specific components which will typically always be Software;  (A possible exception would be an organisation uses custom hardware).  AIH; [IBM pitch WebSphere as Appliction Infrastructure](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/home/wiki/We98b8e939a26_4de1_8977_6a608ae3fc43/page/WebSphere%20Application%20Infrastructure%20Summit?lang=en)  and Microsoft Consider their [Windows Server to the Application Infrasture](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/3/8533724A-1F88-4F19-AB49-690EF9AB3EEB/Gartner-Microsoft%20joint%20newsletter%20-%20Next-generation%20Application%20Infrastructure.pdf) both agree with you and I.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it speaks to HW and SW (middleware and API management).

Gertner definition : Application infrastructure is software platforms for the delivery of business applications, including development and runtime enablers.

Interesting info from Gartner:
http://wso2.com/resources/analyst-reports/comparing-vendors-of-comprehensive-application-infrastructure-suites/